# Read an Encrypted File from folder marked as Encrypted from system account with private key. EFS, Encrypted File System

Tags: encryption, encrypting-file-system

I have a folder Marked as Encrypted (EFS, Encrypted File System). There is a process running in context of a particular user that creates a File which needs to be uploaded by a background service.

The problem is that Background service is getting access denied, background service has access to the certificate which was generated when the folder was marked as Encrypted.

Is there a way background service can access the encrypted file system file through certificate?

Comment: Hey, I know it's quite old question but I'm interested.
What did you do about this?